# How to Send Mail Without Disclosing Recipient's Email Address

Tags: email, outlook, ms-office

I want to send an email in to multiple people via the `To:` field without them knowing that the email was sent to other people.

For the recipient it should look like this:

```
TO: xyz@mail.com
But the actual list should be:

TO: xyz@mail.com; pqr@gmail.com; someone@company.com; everyone@sayari.com;
```

So is it possible to send an email like this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bcc:` ([Blind Carbon Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy)) header/recipients in addition to `To:` header/recipients.

Comment: I have already used Bcc, but in this case the recipient will not see his own email adress... no email adress will be shown.

Comment: If you want every recipient see different to: header then you should send separate messages for every recipient on most (almost all?) mail server